# ¿Qué quiere decir Borges con su “cifra de siglo”?

Tags: definiciones, expresiones

En el pequeño cuento [“Los dos reyes y los dos laberintos” de Jorge Luis Borges](http://www.ciudadseva.com/textos/cuentos/esp/borges/los_dos_reyes_y_los_dos_laberintos.htm) aparece la expresión *cifra del siglo* aquí:

> Lo amarró encima de un camello veloz y lo llevó al desierto. Cabalgaron tres días, y le dijo: “¡Oh, 
>   rey del tiempo y substancia y **cifra del siglo**!, en 
>   Babilonia me quisiste perder en un laberinto de 
>   bronce con muchas escaleras, puertas y muros; ahora 
>   el Poderoso ha tenido a bien que te muestre el mío, 
>   donde no hay escaleras que subir, ni puertas que 
>   forzar, ni fatigosas galerías que recorrer, ni muros 
>   que te veden el paso.”

Bueno, queda claro que este uso de *cifra* es más bien figurativo. Tiene el DRAE [esta entrada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9BkLqAw):

> ## cifra
>
> Del b. lat. *cifra*, este del ár. hisp. *ṣífr*, y este del ár. clás. *ṣifr* ‘vacío’.
>
> 1. f. número dígito.
> 2. f. Signo con que se representa un número dígito.
> 3. f. Escritura en que se usan signos, guarismos o letras convencionales, y que solo puede comprenderse conociendo la clave.
> 4. f. Enlace de dos o más letras, generalmente las iniciales de nombres y apellidos, que como abreviatura se emplea en sellos, marcas, etc.
> 5. f. abreviatura (‖ representación gráfica).
> 6. f. Cantidad de dinero.
> 7. f. Modo vulgar de escribir música por números.
> 8. f. Suma y compendio, emblema.

A mi parecer se trata del último sentido de “sumo y compendio, emblema”: el gran rey de Babilonia es la persona más emblemática y arquetípica de aquella época, su dechado, su mejor ejemplar.

¿Existe alguna otra explicación aquí, o otro sentido?  ¿Puede ser algún juego de palabras, por muy culto que sea?

Lo pregunto porque *cifra* tiene origen en la lengua árabe y su sentido original en ese idioma era “vacío”, y aquí es el rey árabe que dice todo esto en pleno desierto, lejano y vacío.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo interpreto "substancia y cifra" como *cuerpo y alma*, materia y espíritu, realidad e idea, referente y concepto, concreto y abstracto o cualquier pareja similar. Que el rey del tiempo sea *substancia y cifra del siglo* significa  que es a la vez una encarnación del tiempo y una divinidad, entendiendo "cifra" (el signo o el concepto de la cantidad) como lo opuesto a la substancia (la persona concreta).

Esto es una opinión personal. Borges es intencionalmente oscuro e imita el discurso esotérico.

Answer (score 1):

rey del tiempo, asociado a dios; la sustancia (lo escencial), asociado a lo divino?; y la cifra del siglo, con la definición 8, tambien asociado a lo divino o al universo como el "compendio" de todo... en el fondo alude irónicamente a su prepotencia al querer jugar a ser dios o imitarlo

Answer (score 1):

Intentar entender a Borges es como  entrar en el laberinto mismo. Nunca sabes que novedad encontrarás después de leerlo de nuevo. Por lo tanto, esta explicación debe tomarse como una interpretación personal.

Cifra proviene del árabe صفر (Sifr) que significa cero. Otra palabra interesante derivada de Sifr en árabe actual es صرافة (Sirafa) que es significa "Casa/oficina de cambio de divisas". Así, Sifr es al mismo tiempo la nada y el principio, pero también el punto de cambio.

En este pasaje, la palabra siglo es igual de importante. Si buscamos la definición de la RAE. Una de ellas se refiere a la demarcación de una era relativa a un suceso notable que puede estar relaciónada con un personaje en particular.

Así cuando el rey árabe dice "**Oh rey del tiempo y sustancia...**" esta reconociendo (con un dejo de sorna) la importancia en el mundo material de su contraparte porque **era capaz** (antes de ser capturado) **de controlar el tiempo y las vidas de los hombres** al grado de poder construir un laberinto tan complicado. Y luego prosigue "**... y cifra del siglo**" elevándolo aún mas, al implicar que **ha marcado un hito y una era**. Prosigue diciendo el rey árabe al babilonio que era tan grande su poder que fue capaz de someterlo y hacerlo vagar por su laberinto. Al final remata diciendole que a pesar de todo su poder y su importancia ahora le toca a él (al rey babilonio) estar sometido a un nuevo laberinto. Pero este laberinto no ha sido construído por ningún hombre sino por Dios mismo.